# Running PHP in text/javascript environment

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking to run this bit of PHP within a text/javascript environment. The point is to   display a description for certain media files within the Jplayer Playlister. So how can I   run this within a text/javascript environment? If you need an example of the Playerlister working fine, and then breaking upon implementation of the PHP, I can provide that.

Here's the PHP:

```
// CONFIGURE THESE VARIABLES:

// actual place where your mp3s live on your server's filesystem. TRAILING SLASH REQ'D.
$musicDirectory="myServerPathHere";

// corresponding web URL for accessing the music directory. TRAILING SLASH REQ'D.
$musicURL="myURLhere";

// step through each item...

$fileDir = opendir($musicDirectory) or die ($php_errormsg);
while (false !== ($thisFile = readdir($fileDir)))    // step through music directory
{
    $thisFilePath = $musicDirectory . $thisFile;
        if (is_file($thisFilePath) && strrchr ($thisFilePath, '.') == ".mp3") // not . or .., ends in .mp3
        {
            // only include files that have a corresponding .txt file
            $thisTextPath = substr_replace($thisFilePath, ".txt", (strlen($thisFilePath) - 4));
            if (is_file($thisTextPath))
            {
                $myFullURL=$musicURL . $thisFile;
                $myFileSize=filesize($thisFilePath);
                    $textContents = file($thisTextPath);
                    foreach ($textContents as $thisLine) echo htmlspecialchars($thisLine) . "\n";
            }
        }
}
closedir($fileDir);
```

Comment: You cannot execute PHP as if it was J(ava)Script/ECMAScript. What are you *really* looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I don't fully understand what you're asking, so forgive me if that is the case, but what you seem to be asking is how to run PHP client side.

The simple answer is you can't.

PHP is a server-side language. To accomplish what you're trying to do you need to pass some data from PHP to your javascript.

This has always been a bit of a tricky thing to do for me. I usually resort to setting my variables via an on-page `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script>
   var myJSVar = <?= $myPHPVar ?>
</script>
```

I've also used a simple JS object to configure a later script using this same method. There are also some neat tools that enable you to create JSON objects from your PHP objects and pass that to the client side. This makes things pretty smooth, and I recommend you check it out on your own.